# Bitbucket Server Plugin cannot be built because transitive dependency is in no repository

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket

I try upgrading one of our plugins to the new API version of Bitbucket and a transitive dependency cannot be found in any repository. Googeling didn't help yet.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bitbucket-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project orga:bitbucket-plugin:atlassian-plugin:3.3-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.atlassian.bitbucket.server:bitbucket-web-common:jar:8.9.5 -> com.atlassian.bitbucket.server:bitbucket-spi:jar:8.9.5 -> com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-core:jar:7.1.5 -> com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-api:jar:7.1.5 -> io.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:5.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:5.0.0: Could not find artifact io.atlassian.fugue:fugue-parent:pom:5.0.0 in orga.public (https://organexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]`

The Nexus group contains:

- Maven Central
- https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/
- https://packages.atlassian.com/3rdparty/